# CartoDB: Torque animation timeslider

Tags: carto, timeslider, torque

I've an animated torque visualization in CartoDB. The Time Column of animation is date type: 2015-07-03T00:00:00Z
The visualization is ok, but in the mapview the timeslider write the steps like '07/03/2015' (month/day/year). And I want the timeslider write '3 JUL' (day monthshortname).

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Torque formatter is not editable via the CartoDB Editor at this moment. In order to edit it to show a different date format you'd need to use Javascript and the CartoDB.js library.

You can check a working example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/df90d4d4662202894d65), but the key code is:

```
cartodb.createVis('map', 'YOUR_TORQUE_VIZJSON_URL')
        .done(function(vis, layers) {
          //For CartoDB.js versions 3.12 an up
          var slider = vis.timeSlider;
          //For CartoDB.js version 3.11
          //var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')

          slider.formatter(function(d) {

            return d.getUTCDay() + " " + d.getUTCMonth();

          })
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

You might want to edit the line that returns the formatted line, in this case "return d.getUTCDay() + " " + d.getUTCMonth();". [This StackOverflow question could be useful in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643320/get-month-name-from-date).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, but the solution does not work.
This is my code:
`code`'<script>
      function main() {
        cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://grupovocento.cartodb.com/u/colpisa/api/v2/viz/c7885846-2d66-11e5-ac25-0e018d66dc29/viz.json')
        .done(function(vis, layers) {
          var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')
          slider.formatter(function(d) {

            return d.getUTCDay() + " de Julio";

          })
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }

      window.onload = main;
    </script>`code`

Comment: The timeslider not change, is the same (07/03/2015). In the [link] (http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/df90d4d4662202894d65) example does not work, because the timeslider is (09/03/2009) (month/day/year) too and the code of the example is `code`return  d.getUTCMonth()+"-"+ d.getUTCDay() + " "+ d.getUTCHours() + ":"+ d.getUTCMinutes();`code` The hours and the minutes does not writed.

Comment: Oh, I actually updated the version of the CDB.js library without doing the appropriate change. I have fixed the example but it might be cached some time in blocks yet. For CartoDB.js versions 3.12 and up you need to get the timeslider element as var slider = vis.timeSlider;. I have updated the answer too.

Comment: Ok, is fixed!!! The code was wrong. The correct code is var slider = vis.timeSlider; This is my new and ok code `code`.done(function(vis, layers) {
      var slider = vis.getOverlay('time_slider')
      vis.timeSlider.formatter(function(d) {
    return  d.getUTCDate() + " de julio";
})
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  window.onload = main;`code`
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: If the responses were useful, could you mark your question as answered? :)